# In Exception Log want to print data value

Tags: sql

```
declare
  v number;
  c varchar2(20);
begin

  select c into v from dual;
exception
  when others
  then
    raise;
end;
```

while running this block i am getting exception because i m providing input on c dynamically (suppose) as character. i want raise will print the error with value of C.
Is there any way that we can add message + value of C in raise statement.

Answer (score 0):

By adding simple :

```
Select CONCAT(raise,'C');
```

will print its value in the console

Comment: Is there any way that we can add message + value of C in raise statement